# How to recursively create a constexpr list using Boost hana ?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, template-meta-programming

I had asked a question before about creating a compiletime list data structure and was advised to use Boost.hana

I tried this basic test code:

```
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/concat.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template<typename A, typename R> 
constexpr R parse(A count)
{
  if(count == 0)
  {
    return hana::make_tuple(0);
  }
  else
  {
    return parse(count - 1);
  }
}


int main() 
{ 
  constexpr auto l = parse(10);

  hana::for_each
  (
    l, 
    [](auto const& element) 
    {
      std::cout << element << std::endl;
    }
  );

}
```

However, the template type deduction isn't working, because each invocation of the recursive function returns a different type.
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The main thing you have to understand when doing metaprogramming with hana is that there aren't values - we're not manipulating things like numbers, we're manipulating types. Those types may have values associated with them, but they're still types. The term for that is [IntegralConstant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1IntegralConstant.html).

What you want is something like:

```
template <class C> 
constexpr auto parse(C count)
{
    if constexpr(count == 0_c) {
        return hana::tuple(count);
    } else {
        return hana::flatten(hana::make_tuple(
            hana::tuple(count),
            parse(count - 1_c)));
    }
}

constexpr auto l = parse(10_c);
```

`10_c` is an instance of an IntegralConstant whose value is `10`. We can compare this to `0_c` in the base case. That looks like value equality, which is the really nice thing about using Hana, but it's not value equality - it's purely type based.

The result of `parse(10_c)` is the compile-time tuple equivalent of `<10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0>`.

---

Note that this:

```
template<typename A, typename R> 
constexpr R parse(A count);
```

is not a particularly usable function template, because `R` is a non-deduced context and thus must be specified at the call-site. Which made `parse(10)` ill-formed regardless of the body of `parse()`.